# Ring self-intersection error when running Random Points

Tags: qgis, self-intersection

This error occurs on two rows of my shapefile:

> Feature (650) has invalid geometry. Please fix the geometry or change
>   the Processing setting to the "Ignore invalid input features" option.
>   Execution failed after 1.82 seconds

Is there a relatively easy way to fix?

On the image below the error message and the way my features look like are represented

[image: Error_example]

Comment: In the processing there is an algorithm called fix invalid geometry. Run that first and then execute your main algorithm

Comment: Thank you. This fixed the problem.